# Hadoop: I am not able to connect to localhost:8088 (yarn resource manager)

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am using kali linux and I am a beginner. I installed everything related to hadoop.
when I run start-all.sh, I am able to connect to the http://localhost:50070/ but not to the localhost:8088

Below is my file configurations:

```
root@SHUBHAM-PC:/usr/local/hadoop/conf# cat yarn-site.xml 
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
   <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
 </property>
</configuration>

root@SHUBHAM-PC:/usr/local/hadoop/conf# cat hdfs-site.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<!-- specify this so that running 'hadoop namenode -format'
formats the right dir -->
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>/usr/local/hadoop/cache/hadoop/dfs/name</value>
</property>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.data.dir</name> 
      <value>/usr/local/hadoop/cache/hadoop/dfs/data </value> 
   </property>
</configuration>

root@SHUBHAM-PC:/usr/local/hadoop/conf# cat mapred-site.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>localhost:8021</value>
</property>
```

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Your configuration are wrong. You are using yarn and job tracker at same time which is not possible I guess.

Comment: You can find plenty of materials on internet for instance https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Comment: thank you! the site is really helpful. my problem is resolved

Comment: @ShubhamJoshi I have the same problem and unable to fix it despite following the hadoop.apache.org link. Both localhost:50070 and localhost:50090 work. But localhost:8088 does not work. Did you happen to fix anything else along with the steps given on the link?